# What are tshark's default output fields?

Tags: tshark

I'm trying to expand tshark's output. On the first round I haven't found simple solution, only that one can extract a field by the -e option, so the following command outputs

- frame number
- time from beginning of capture
- source ip address
- destination ip address
- http request uri
- and the http content lenght, which I want to add to the default output.

*tshark -T fields -e frame.number -e frame.time_relative -e ip.src -e ip.dst http.request.uri -e http.content_length*

My problem is, that I can't find the default output field names or an option that leaves them and append the desired fields to it.

It's not mandatory, but would be nice to know : )

Answer (score 12):

This is not exactly the default output but comes quite close:

`tshark -T fields -e frame.number -e frame.time_delta -e _ws.col.Source -e _ws.col.Destination -e _ws.col.Protocol -e ip.len  -e _ws.col.Info`

Comment: is there a way to show the arrow icon between `-e _ws.col.Source` and `-e _ws.col.Destination` ?