# How to add an extra column to Tshark's output (while keeping the default ones)?

Tags: wireshark, tshark

I would like to add a Tshark column that tells me which type of ICMP-packet has been captured. This would be the following: icmp.type

While I still  need the default columns, how can I make Tshark also show this one?

I've already seen the option to work with -T fields and -e but then all the default columns are left out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the default columns and use for instance:

`tshark -i 1 -T fields -e frame.number -e frame.time -e eth.src -e eth.dst -e frame.protocols -e _ws.col.Protocol -e _ws.col.Info -e icmp.type -E header=y > output.csv`

See tshark -h or the [man-page](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) for more information.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49661356/516188

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add something to the default summary output, you can also use:

> -z proto,colinfo,filter,field

For example something like:

> -z proto,colinfo,tcp.seq,tcp.seq

Will show this:

> 1 2018-10-10 10:39:54 192.168.0.10 -> 192.168.0.1 SSH 198 Encrypted response packet len=132  tcp.seq == 1