# How to add arrow icon to specified output of tshark?

Tags: wireshark, tshark

Default output of tshark has an arrow icon between `_ws.col.Source` and `_ws.col.Destination` like this:

```
13   1.001761 192.168.1.246 → dns.google   ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x1d5b, seq=48154/6844, ttl=63
```

When I apply my own specified output, referring to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49661356/6929908), the `→` icon disappears.

```
13   1.001761 192.168.1.246  dns.google   ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x1d5b, seq=48154/6844, ttl=63
```

What should I do to show the the `→` icon to the output when I need to use my own filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't achieve this using `-T fields`, but you can by specifying the column format option.

Compare the output of this:

> tshark.exe -T fields -e frame.number -e frame.time_delta -e _ws.col.Source
> -e _ws.col.Destination -e _ws.col.Protocol -e ip.len  -e _ws.col.Info

... with the output of this:

**Windows:**

> tshark.exe -o
> "gui.column.format:\"No.\",\"%m\",\"DeltaTime\",\"%Gt\",\"Source\",\"%s\",\"Destination\",\"%d\",\"Protocol\",\"%p\",\"IP
> Length\",\"%Cus:ip.len\",\"Info\",\"%i\""

***nix:**

> tshark.exe -o
> 'gui.column.format:"No.","%m","DeltaTime","%Gt","Source","%s","Destination","%d","Protocol","%p","IP
> Length","%Cus:ip.len","Info","%i"'

Run `tshark -G column-formats` for more information about the column formats.